# Order by last 3 chars

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

```
id  name
--------
1   clark_009
2   clark_012
3   johny_002
4   johny_010
```

I need to get results in this order:

```
johny_002
clark_009
johny_010
clark_012
```

Do not ask me what I already tried, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This will do it, very simply selecting the right-most 3 characters and ordering by that value ascending.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY RIGHT(name, 3) ASC;
```

It should be added that as your data grows, this will become an inefficient solution.  Eventually, you'll probably want to store the numeric appendix in a separate, indexed integer column, so that sorting will be optimally efficient.

Comment: You may want to RTRIM it too just in case: `ORDER BY RIGHT(RTRIM(name), 3 ASC;`

Comment: `RIGHT` is doing really right stuff :) seems i just overseen it, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

you should try this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table order by SUBSTRING(name, -3);
```

good luck!

Comment: Note: This for MySQL - works for MySQL! Not Microsoft SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 6):

**You can use MySQL `SUBSTRING()` function to sort by substring**

> **Syntax :** `SUBSTRING(string,position,length)`

**Example :** Sort by last 3 characters of a String

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY SUBSTRING(FieldName, -3);
#OR
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY SUBSTRING(FieldName, -3,3);
```

**Example :** Sort by first 3 characters of a String

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY SUBSTRING(FieldName, 1,3);
```

> **Note :** `Positive` Position/Index start from Left to Right and `Negative` Position/Index start from Right to Left of the String.

Here is the details about   [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function.

Comment: Your explanation helps a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You may apply substring_index function to parse these values -

```
select * from table order by substring_index(name, '_', -1)
```

Comment: Good alternate solution, ordering by everything following the '_' rather than by a fixed # of characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by the last three characters (from left to right) with variable name lengths, I propose this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY SUBSTRING (name, LEN(name)-2, 3)
```

The index starts at lenght of name -2 which is the third last character.

I'm a little late but just encountered the same problem and this helped me.