# ORDER BY using REGEXP in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am fiddling around `REGEXP` in MySQL, and I was wondering how the `ORDER BY` command could be used with `REGEXP` in a situation like e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732026/order-by-last-3-chars), where we would normally order by the last 3 chars of a column using `ORDER BY RIGHT(COL,3)`.

I tried this query

```
SELECT COL FROM TABLE ORDER BY (COL REGEXP "\w{3}$") ASC
```

but it doesn't work. Can I fix it somehow to get the equivalent of `RIGHT(COL,3)` ?

Comment: Why not just use `RIGHT(columnname,3)`?

Comment: Cause I think that a regexp can be much more versatile/powerful than a mySQL function like RIGHT(), and cause I'm just curious if it's possible to do it :)

Comment: Regex is much more versatile than string functions, but the latter is much faster in the great majority of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`col REGEXP '...'` return a true/false (actually 1/0) value.  To `ORDER BY` col REGEXP '...'` you get the rows that don't *match* first (in arbitrary order), followed by the ones that do match.  It does *not* sort by the last 3 characters.

Use `ORDER BY RIGHT(col, 3)`.

Aliasing is a convenience, not a performance issue, here.

If you are looking for the `com` at the end of a domain, keep in mind that not all are exactly 3 characters.  So, instead, use

```
ORDER BY  SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, '.', -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alias a column and then order by the aliased column. Your query would look like:

```
SELECT COL, (COL REGEXP "\w{3}$") AS MyOrderedCol FROM TABLE ORDER BY MyOrderedCol ASC
```

Comment: (1) That still does not do the task. (2) Aliasing does not help much, if any.